# APIProjectMapError when using WP Google Map plugin to display map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

My client's Google Map recently stopped working due (I think) to previous developer suspending his Google account and related API key. I've set up a new project with billing enabled and have a new API key but the map is still not displaying.

I have entered the new API key into the plugin, emptied cache and deleted and reinstalled the plugin. I have enabled Maps Javascript API, Maps Static API, Geocoding and Places and entered HTTP referrers.

This code appears in line 52 as flagged in the console.

```
_.Uc=function(a){for(var b=[],c=0;c<arguments.length;++c)b[c-0]=arguments[c];_.y.console&&_.y.console.error&&_.y.console.error.apply(_.y.console,_.wa(b))};Vc=function(a){this.message=a;this.name="InvalidValueError";this.stack=Error().stack};_.Wc=function(a,b){var c="";if(null!=b){if(!(b instanceof Vc))return b;c=": "+b.message}return new Vc(a+c)};_.Xc=function(a){if(!(a instanceof Vc))throw a;_.Uc(a.name+": "+a.message)};
```

Instead of a map I get a 'Sorry, something went wrong' message.

The browser developer console is showing Google Maps Javascript API error: `APIProjectMapError`. It also displays `js?key=` and then includes the **old** key rather than the new one.

Could you please advise me on how to update a Google API Key in WP Google Map plugin and remove the old key from cache?

Comment: Seems like you haven't actually included the new key on the page.

Comment: Which page? I copied and pasted the new key into the WP Google Maps plugin. Is there another step I need to take? Thanks.

Comment: The page that is displaying the old key in the Javascript console

Comment: Please could you advise as to how I would go about doing this? The documentation I read suggested that if I pasted the new key into the plugin, I would not need to interfere with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) `ApiProjectMapError` is returned when:

> Either the provided API key or the API project with which it is
>   associated, could not be resolved. This error may be temporary. If
>   this error message persists you may need to get a new API key or
>   create a new API project.

If you have applied the API key in your WP dashboard from the [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com), then there must be a problem with the plugin which the support team of your plugin can help you determine. You may also reach out for the [support team](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support) of the Google Maps Platform as they might also help you with the issue.

I strongly suggest that you reach out to the support teams that was mentioned above as your issue involves API key which you cannot share publicly due to security reasons.